# How to sum contributions in searchkit?

Tags: searchkit

Sorry for the very basic question but I'm a bit stumped!

I want to create a donors report with searchkit.  Something simple : name and total donations.

I see in this answer an option to "sum" a column.  But when I look on my install (Civi 5.52.2) I don't see that option.  And when I look on dmaster.demo I also don't see that option (see screenshot).

Where can I find the "sum" field transform?

[image: dmaster.demo showing no sum option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the contributions entity under "Search For", and then group by Contact ID. Then you will see the sum option under field transformations.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!